# Python encoding function can't be decoded

Tags: python, encoding, pickle, decoding

I wrote this python code in an attempt to convert objects to a string of ones and zeros, but the decoding fails because the data can't be unpickled. This is the code:

```
def encode(obj):
    'convert an object to ones and zeros'
    def tobin(str):
        rstr = ''
        for f in str:
            if f == "0": rstr += "0000"
            elif f == "1": rstr += "0001"
            elif f == "2": rstr += "0010"
            elif f == "3": rstr += "0100"
            elif f == "4": rstr += "1000"
            elif f == "5": rstr += "1001"
            elif f == "6": rstr += "1010"
            elif f == "7": rstr += "1100"
            elif f == "8": rstr += "1101"
            elif f == "9": rstr += "1110"
            else: rstr += f
        return rstr
    import pickle, StringIO
    f = StringIO.StringIO()
    pickle.dump(obj, f)
    data = f.getvalue()
    import base64
    return tobin(base64.b16encode(base64.b16encode(data)))
def decode(data):
    def unbin(data):
        rstr = ''
        for f in data:
            if f == "0000": rstr += "0"
            elif f == "0001": rstr += "1"
            elif f == "0010": rstr += "2"
            elif f == "0100": rstr += "3"
            elif f == "1000": rstr += "4"
            elif f == "1001": rstr += "5"
            elif f == "1010": rstr += "6"
            elif f == "1100": rstr += "7"
            elif f == "1101": rstr += "8"
            elif f == "1110": rstr += "9"
        return rstr
    import base64
    ndata = base64.b16decode(base64.b16decode(unbin(data)))
    import pickle, StringIO
    f = StringIO.StringIO(ndata)
    obj = pickle.load(f)
    return obj
```

Comment: You do know that Python has a `bin()` function built-in?

Comment: His binary string transform is somewhat mangled (e.g. 0100 <-> 3)

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: `tobin` is not performing a binary conversion.

Comment: It's not supposed to convert the numbers to binary. It only is supposed to make them ones and zeros

Comment: Just to clarify: What you're doing here doesn't qualify as **encryption** -- it's really just an **encoding** of the data.  In fact, it looks a lot like Gray code: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code .  It certainly doesn't provide much security: it could be pretty trivially brute-forced.

Comment: I edited the question to change the terminology (encrypt → encode, decrypt → decode) since this is a serious error that might badly confuse a future questioner.  Please see <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code> and <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption> for more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are several problems, but one is that when you decode, you need to iterate through groups of 4 characters in you unbin() function, not single characters like you are currently doing.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it so it iterates through 4 characters and now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a better solution for you. This should be even more secure, since it "encrypts" everything, not just numbers:

```
MAGIC = 0x15 # CHOOSE ANY TWO HEX DIGITS YOU LIKE

# THANKS TO NAS BANOV FOR THE FOLLOWING:
unbin = tobin = lambda s: ''.join(chr(ord(c) ^ MAGIC) for c in s)
```

Comment: optimization `unbin = tobin` instead of `def unbin` :-D

Comment: @Nas Banov I was wondering if you could do that. I don't use python at all and was pretty much just copying syntax from the asker. :)

Comment: Yeah, you can. But now i notice something in your code - you can't use `^` on a string. And since we are getting kinky, here is  replacement is suggest: `unbin = tobin = lambda s: ''.join(chr(ord(c) ^ MAGIC) for c in s)`

Comment: @Nas Banov Ah I assumed the for would be throwing off characters, not strings. Thanks for the corrections.

Answer (score 0):

Your `bin` and `unbin` functions aren't inverses of each other, because `bin` has an else clause that just puts the characters verbatim into the output, but `unbin` has no else clause to pass them back.

Comment: The else there should be made to throw exception, since it is by design unreachable - base64.b16encode(base64.b16encode()) ensures there are only digits

Answer (score 0):

By the way... `base64.b16encode(base64.b16encode(data))` is equivalent to `data.encode('hex').encode('hex')`. And there is simpler and faster way to do the mapping,

```
def tobin(numStr):
    return ''.join(("0000","0001","0010","0100","1000","1001","1010","1100","1101","1110")[int(c)] for c in numStr)
```

The whole idea of this encoding, while seeming complicated on the surface, is not very good. First, it does not do much of encryption, since each digit from the hex dump gets matched always to the same 8-length string of 0 and 1s:

```
>>> hexd = '0123456789ABCDEF'
>>> s = hexd.encode('hex')
>>> s
'30313233343536373839414243444546'
>>> s=''.join(["0000","0001","0010","0100","1000","1001","1010","1100","1101","1110"][int(c)] for c in s)
>>> s
'01000000010000010100001001000100010010000100100101001010010011000100110101001110100000011000001010000100100010001000100110001010'
>>> for i in range(0,len(s),8):
...     print hexd[i/8], s[i:i+8], chr(int(s[i:i+8],2))
... 
0 01000000 @
1 01000001 A
2 01000010 B
3 01000100 D
4 01001000 H
5 01001001 I
6 01001010 J
7 01001100 L
8 01001101 M
9 01001110 N
A 10000001 
B 10000010 ‚
C 10000100 „
D 10001000 ˆ
E 10001001 ‰
F 10001010 Š
```

Secondly, it blows up the size of the pickled object **16 times**! Even if you pack this by converting every 8 bits of '0' and '1' to bytes (say `chr(int(encoded[i:i+8],2))`), that still is **2x** the pickle.